# LLVM IR: Get LVALUE operand

Tags: c++, llvm-ir

I have following instruction:

```
%ptrA = getelementptr float, float addrspace(1)* %A, i32 %id
```

I can get the operands `%A` and `%id` using `getOperand(0)` and `getOperand(1)`. I was wondering if `getOperand` will work on `%ptrA`? If yes, would it be `getOperand(3)`?

------------------------------------Edit----------------------------

So I changed my code as follows:

```
for (Instruction &I : instructions(F)){
    if (cast<Operator>(I).getOpcode() == Instruction::GetElementPtr){
        Value* AddrPointer = cast<Value>(I);
```

I keep getting error:

```
error: cannot convert ‘llvm::Value’ to ‘llvm::Value*’ in initialization
       Value* AddrPointer = cast<Value>(I);
                                         ^
```

I see that there is some problem with type mismatch.

Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your question lacks quite a bit of context, but I will assume you're working with an `llvm::Instruction *` representing that particular `getelementptr` instruction. No, `getOperand()` will not allow you to access `%ptrA`. In general, `getOperand()` only allows access to the instruction's operands, or arguments, but not its return value. In IR, `%ptrA` is not so much an operand of the instruction like in traditional assembly, but can be thought of more like the *return value* of the instruction.

The syntax for what you're trying to do is actually very convenient. An `llvm::Instruction` object itself represents its own return value. In fact, `llvm::Instruction` is a derived class of `llvm::Value`. You can use `llvm::cast`, with `llvm::Value` as the template argument and the result will actually be an `llvm::Value *` which represents the return value of `getelementptr`.

```
llvm::Instruction * instruc;

//next line assumes instruc has your getelementptr instruction

llvm::Value * returnval = llvm::cast<llvm::Value>(instruc);
//returnval now contains the result of the instruction
//you could potentially create new instructions with IRBuilder using returnval as an argument, and %ptrA would actually be passed as an operand to those instructions
```

Furthermore, many of the functions that actually create instructions (the `llvm::IRBuilder::Create*` instructions, for instance) don't even return `llvm::Instruction *`s but rather `llvm::Value *`s. This is very convenient, because most of the time if you need to feed the return value of an instruction into another instruction, you can simply pass the return value of whatever `Create` function you called into the next `Create` function, without needing to do any casting.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I want to gather all the `%ptrA` etc. pointers into a data structure by iterating over a function, to use them later. So I believe by returning the name of the instruction pointer I can use it just like the operands of that instruction, right? (Sorry for the overt simplification, new to LLVM.)

Comment: When you say you're trying to populate a data structure with the "`%ptrA` pointers" are you trying to populate a data structure within your IR program? Or are you trying to populate a data structure in the parent C++ program? What are you trying to populate it with, the contents of `%ptrA`, or something else? I'm still having trouble understanding what you're trying to do.

Comment: Hi. So I have an LLVM IR for CUDA kernel function. I am trying to instrument the LD/ST instructions belonging to each thread. Now the `GetElementPtr` declares each thread's id to the respective pointer and in subsequent instructions, I try to instrument the LD/ST instructions associated to that pointer. I hope this is clear. Sorry for being too concise earlier, that can be a problem. I appreciate your help.

Comment: `llvm::Value * returnval = llvm::cast<llvm::Value>(instruc);`

Comment: Alright, I think I see now. Yeah, as an example, you could feed returnval as shown as one of the parameters to whichever `IRBuilder::Create*` function you're using to create your ld/st instructions. Although I'm guessing in your case it will be some type of array of `llvm::Value *` rather than a single element. That would produce an IR instruction which used the result of your `getelementptr` as one of its parameters.

Comment: I am creating an instruction just to 'trace' the preceding LD or ST instruction. So what you have said here is what I am doing. Thanks again.